# update table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I often see queries or SPs have these DML statement in my company here.

```
update #tablename
set Balance = 1
From #tablename
```

(or)

```
update #tablename
set Balance =1
From #tablename tn
INNER JOIN 
(Select distinct employeeID from myEmployee) Emp
ON tn.EmpID = Emp.EmpID
```

My questions:

1. I do not understand why we need `From #tablename` in the first query. As I usually write the only first two lines in that query.
2. What they do in the 2nd query? Can't it be done in another or more readable way?

Comment: In first query you don't need `from` clause. In second query they updating the `empid` in `#temptable` which is present in `myEmployee` table.

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Thank you, but I am afraid I do not understand your statement on 2nd query explanation

Comment: In second query they are updating the rows `balance=1` in `#tablename` only when the `empid` is present in `myEmployee` table

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Thank you, I agree with you now :) :)

Comment: Guess question can be closed

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Oh yes, sure :) I think you are very active, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, the `from` clause is not necessary.

The second query is probably not doing what the authors intend.  This query:

```
update #tablename
    set Balance =1
    From #tablename tn INNER JOIN 
         (Select distinct employeeID from myEmployee) Emp
         ON tn.EmpID = Emp.EmpID;
```

Is going to update every row in `#tablename`.  The intention is probably:

```
update tn
    set Balance = 1
    From #tablename tn INNER JOIN 
         (Select distinct employeeID from myEmployee) Emp
         ON tn.EmpID = Emp.EmpID;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you, however, I have no clue of what second query is doing? I can not understand the syntax and its outcome. Could you please help me understand? What I understand is "Set Balance =1" would set balance = 1 :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning value to update in table directly(ie: set a=1).
Then there is no need of writing from table and where conditions

If you want to update table with values of other table then go with second query

Comment: Thank you, everyone's opinion here on 2nd query differs, I am confused what does it do.